# custom function to merge two csv files based on common cloumn with different names

Tags: python, pandas

```
a,b,c
5,Ugh,wq
2,Kj,asd
3,Yu,Dx
4,Po,Cv

d,e
3,8i
4,Y6
2,X09
5,m3
```

Write a function that uses pandas create_result(“X.a|X.b|X.c|Y.e” , “X.a=Y.d”)

This will create result.csv with columns from X and Y as passed as parameters as above, and column values are mapped according to the key between the 2 files, specified as 2nd parameter - X.a and Y.d

result should be like this

```
a,b,c,f
5,Ugh,wq,m3
2,Kj,asd,X09
3,Yu,Dx,8i
4,Po,Cv,Y6
```

i have tried a function like this

```
x=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Venkata sai/Desktop/SQL_VENKATASAI_ASSIGNMENT/test/X.csv")
y=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Venkata sai/Desktop/SQL_VENKATASAI_ASSIGNMENT/test/Y.csv")
print(x)
print(y)

def create_result(x,y):
    merged=pd.merge(x,y,on='x.a=y.d')
    print(merged)
    merged.to_csv("resultstable.csv",index=false)
```

i am not getting the desired output.

Comment: You should read the documentation of pd.merge. The right way is this:
    ```merged=pd.merge(x,y,left_on='a', right_on='d')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `rename` column and merge by `a` from both `DataFrame`s:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2.rename(columns={'d':'a'}), on='a')
print (df)
   a    b    c    e
0  5  Ugh   wq   m3
1  2   Kj  asd  X09
2  3   Yu   Dx   8i
3  4   Po   Cv   Y6
```